# C++ stack allocated variable not destructed (/destroyed?)

Tags: c++, destructor

I'm quite new to C++ but I think I'm right in that saying objects declared on the stack should automagically be destructed/destroyed when they go out of scope? In the mini-project I'm working with at the moment, this isn't the case.

```
void MainWindow::clickTest() {
    FunkyNumber num = 4;
    FunkyNumber num2 = 6;

    num += num2;
    std::cout << num << std::endl; // This works okay!

    // Should be destroyed here!
}
```

My destructor should do this:

```
virtual FunkyNumber::~FunkyNumber() {
    std::cout << "goodbye cruel world! (" << m_intValue << ")" << std::endl;
    // m_intValue is just the int value of this "FunkyNumber"
}
```

But nothing comes out into standard out!

Should probably mention I'm using Qt - but this is just a plain C++ class and so this shouldn't really matter from what I can tell...

EDIT:
funkynumber.cpp:

```
#include "funkynumber.h"

FunkyNumber::FunkyNumber(int num)
     : m_intValue(num) {
     std::cout << "made a funkynumber " << num << std::endl;
}

FunkyNumber::~FunkyNumber() {
    std::cout << "goodbye cruel world! (" << m_intValue << ")" << std::endl;
}

int FunkyNumber::intValue() const {
    return m_intValue;
}

void FunkyNumber::operator+=(const FunkyNumber &other) {
    m_intValue += other.intValue();
}

void FunkyNumber::operator=(const FunkyNumber &other) {
    m_intValue = other.intValue();
}

bool FunkyNumber::operator==(const FunkyNumber &other) {
    return other.intValue() == m_intValue;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &outStream, const FunkyNumber &num) {
    outStream << "FunkyNumber (" << num.intValue() << ")";

    return outStream;
}
```

Comment: The objects are being destroyed, you are just not seeing it for whatever reason.

Comment: can you add the entire FunkyNumber  class to the post please?

Comment: Would have to see more code -- could be something as simple as your destructor implementation isn't being used and the default (empty) destructor is being called instead.

Comment: Use the debugger and set a breakpoint in your destructor.

Comment: Are you running that in a console/terminal?

Comment: The code you've shown should operate exactly as you expect. You need to provide more details.

Comment: I'd love to help, but my crystal ball is currently being serviced! Seriously, how can you expect us to help if you won't show code? Provide an SSCCE.

Comment: Okay okay, I didn't know if that would be enough information for someone well versed in C++ to diagnose it! Please see above for an edit with the full source of FunkyNumber.cpp. Should probably mention the constructor output is visible, just not the destructor!

Comment: Try to output something after clickTest() method returns - probably destructor output is not flushed to output stream.

Comment: Please prove an SSCCE. You can put all you need to reproduce this in a single file. Should be feasible in around 15-20 lines of code.

Comment: @luriCovalisin doubt it, `std::endl` flushes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not reproduce the behavior.

```
#include<iostream>

struct FunkyNumber{
    int m_intValue;
    FunkyNumber::FunkyNumber(int num)
        : m_intValue(num) {
            std::cout << "made a funkynumber " << num << std::endl;
    }

    FunkyNumber::~FunkyNumber() {
        std::cout << "goodbye cruel world! (" << m_intValue << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    int FunkyNumber::intValue() const {
        return m_intValue;
    }

    void FunkyNumber::operator+=(const FunkyNumber &other) {
        m_intValue += other.intValue();
    }

    void FunkyNumber::operator=(const FunkyNumber &other) {
        m_intValue = other.intValue();
    }

    bool FunkyNumber::operator==(const FunkyNumber &other) {
        return other.intValue() == m_intValue;
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &outStream, const FunkyNumber &num) {
    outStream << "FunkyNumber (" << num.intValue() << ")";

    return outStream;
}

void call(){
    FunkyNumber num = 4;
    FunkyNumber num2 = 6;

    num += num2;
    std::cout << num << std::endl; // This works okay!

    // Should be destroyed here!
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    call();
    std::cout << "call ended" << std::endl;
}
```

This works fine. The reason why people promote [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is not only to make it easier to help you but also because it can help you find where the issue is yourself(which is clearly not in the code you posted).

Comment: You're going to be really disappointed, but I just recompiled the project (clean & build), and now it works as it should do! Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a Windows GUI application (Windows application with a `WinMain` entry point)?

If it is, the standard output does not get displayed automatically when running it from the command line. I am not sure why this is, but IIRC running:

```
myapp | cat
```

should cause the standard output to be setup correctly.